# How do I hide a dependency when bundler is running "bundle install"?

Tags: ruby, bundle, bundler, gemfile

Currently, when I run "bundle install" the output displays the username and gemfile of my private repo.  I would like to hide this output and change it to something else.

Right now:

```
Updating https://user:password@github.com/sc/models.git
```

I would like:

```
Updating https://user:XXXXXXXX@github.com/sc/models.git
```

Comment: Is ssh authentication an option?

Comment: SSH was not working because sc/models.git is a private repo, and is used in Jenkins and Heroku.

Comment: unless Im mistaken, being a private repo isn't a reason, just provide a key pair that allow authorization... If you ever need to block access to github later, you can remove the keypair from github.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this looks like a bug report / feature request for bundler, please open a ticket here:

https://github.com/carlhuda/bundler/issues/new